# Updating each data attribute on page

Tags: jquery

I have a series of `a` tags on page. They are all the same, something like this:

```
<a class="follow-user 50126cec60de7d7467000003" data-followers_count="1 Follower" href="#">
Test User
</a>
```

I'm trying to iterarte through all the elements of `a` and changing the `data-followers_count`. I'm unable to do so even though no errors are returned.

```
$("body").on("click", ".btn-follow", function(e) {
    var el, linkContent;
    e.preventDefault();
    el = $(this);
    user_id = '50126cec60de7d7467000003';
    linkContent = $(document).find('.follow-user.' + user_id);
    $.each(linkContent, function(index) {
        $(this).data('followers_count', 'new count');
        //alert('Changed to ' + $(this).data('followers_count'));
    });
});​
```

Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/netwire88/Zrrvq/2/

Any ideas?

Comment: your code is indeed working as expected. Firebug is not showing the changes live however. Try doing a `console.log($(this).data('followers_count'));` after changing the value inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$("body").on("click", ".btn-follow", function(e) {
    var el, linkContent, popoverContent, urlString, user_id;
    e.preventDefault();
    el = $(this);
    user_id = '50126cec60de7d7467000003';
    $('.follow-user.' + user_id).each(function(index) {
        $(this).data('followers_count', 'new count');
        alert($(this).data('followers_count')); //confirms changed
    });
});​
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zrrvq/7/

Comment: Hmm... I was unsuccessful. I ended up trying Gon.

Comment: Not, sure, may be there's some other conflicts in the code? But I wasn't able to get Knockout/Backbone to work, because that'd make this easier.